# Latest time updated from two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have project model and comment model. I need to show  project last updated if project or comment is changed. If one model means I will do `project.updated_at`, but I need to check `comment.updated_at` also. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method `last_updated` in your Project model...

If you have many comments per model...

```
def last_updated
  most_recent_comment = comments.order(updated_at: :desc).first
  return updated_at unless most_recent_comment
  [most_recent_comment.updated_at, updated_at].max
end
```

Now you can use `my_project.last_updated` and it will return the most recent date between comment or project (whichever is greater) or will return just project date if no comments currently exist.